# minimum reduced string made up of a,b,c

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, string-algorithm

This is an interview questions asked from me.

An input string is made up of only `a`, `b` and `c`. You have to reduce the string to minimum possible length. Reducing criteria is:

if `ab` or `ba` comes together, it can be replaced by `c`

if `bc` or `cb` comes together, it can be replaced by `a`

if `ac` or `ca` comes together, it can be replaced by `b`

For example,

ab**cb**ca --> **ab**aca --> c**ac**a --> cba --> cc or aa

**ab**cbca --> c**cb**ca --> caca --> same as above

I could not even think of any proper logic. I started thinking in terms of odd and even place occurrence, but it did not help. Please help me in buildinga logic for it

Thanks

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz I could not find the question.Thanks, i am also voting for closing it.